# objects.filter by User filters data only for one user

Tags: python, django, serialization

I want to filter data from the model, using user PK (the best way it is using session, but I don't know how works with).

`model.py`:

```
class Fca(models.Model):
    num_of_agree = models.ForeignKey(Agreement, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    uroch = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    num_allot = models.ForeignKey(Allotment, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    num_fca = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    ar_fca = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    expl_ar = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    cel_nazn = models.ForeignKey(ForestPurpose, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='task',blank=True, null=True) 
    cat_zas = models.ForeignKey(ForestProtection, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='cate',blank=True, null=True ) 
    geom = models.MultiPolygonField(geography=True, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='ge')
    video_cat = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    user_check = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='user_id',blank=True, null=True )

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        verbose_name = 'lek'
        verbose_name_plural =  'leks'
```

So `user_check` is a filter.

`serializer.py`:

```
class FcaSerializer(gis_serializers.GeoFeatureModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Fca
        geo_field = 'geom'
        fields = ('id','num_of_agree','num_allot','uroch','num_fca','ar_fca',\
       'expl_ar','cel_nazn','cat_zas','geom','video_cat','user_check')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Fca.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

and the view queryset def:

```
class FcaSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = FcaSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user.pk
        return Fca.objects.filter(user_check = user)
```

So when I login user with pk 1, app shows relevant data (where the user has pk 1). `/api/fcaapi/` shows only relevant data too. But when I use other users, with pk 3 for example, the app shows the same data (where pk of the user is 1). What is wrong? How to show only relevant data for User?

propreties API responce :

```
"properties": {
                    "num_of_agree": null,
                    "num_allot": 225,
                    "uroch": null,
                    "num_fca": null,
                    "ar_fca": null,
                    "expl_ar": null,
                    "cel_nazn": 1,
                    "cat_zas": 1,
                    "video_cat": null,
                    "user_check": 1
                }
```

Comment: What is the `user_check` value from the API response?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Do you always want the ID from the URL, rather than from the logged-in user? If so why are you using `self.request.user`?

Comment: @JPG I UPD this info.

Comment: And what do your URLs look like?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Hello. I want that  user see only himself data. And I thought using pk like a filter is simple way (maybe without security, but it is study project). So I want to know how filter data by user.

Comment: Ok, but you still need to show your URLs. Does the URL pattern for this view have a user id?

Comment: @DanielRoseman maybe I don't understand you are, I'm sorry. Where I have to set user id? I set user id like foreign_key in model and serializer, it isn't enough? url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)), and for this , model view url is router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'cutarea-fca-use', FcaUseSet, base_name='cutarea-fca-use').

Comment: Now I really don't understand. If you want to get a user ID from the URL, surely you realise that you need to put a user ID in that URL?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want to filter data by  "user_check":  values. (ist is foreign key of user model) It is possible?

Comment: Sigh. Yes of course it's possible. **But where is the ID to use in that filter coming from?**

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm sorry)) ID from standart django User model table.

Answer (score 0):

If you face with problem like this check that you set in settings.py 'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication